# Payment Gateway integration issue with global iris

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

Our application is working n NoP commerce and we are trying to integrate payment gateway with HSBC bank payment gateway but after successful payment it gives me following error:

***Your transaction has been successful but there was a problem connecting back to the merchant's web site. Please contact the merchant and advise them that you received this error message. Thank you.***

I tried to do googling but did not find any proper solution for it.

Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the payment gateway can't connect to your callback page. Also, I have received such error with another payment provider if there is an exception on the callback page. try to see if the payment process returns to your callback page, and first thing you do on the page is to log details.

Comment: Hi Junai, thanks for your answer. Let me log the details if possible

Comment: Hi Junaid, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it has worked well and now our site is working fine.

Comment: @HarshilShukla thanks great, can you please mark my answer by selecting the tick next to this answer. This would help you to increase your reputation as well. Thanks.